# Make Google Assistant listen for 1 minute

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, assistant

I want to make the Assistant leave the microphone open for the user to dictate for up to 1 minute maximum. I somehow want to make it close the microphone only if there previously were 10 seconds of silence.

At the moment the mic closes if the user has stopped speaking at any moment.
I'm not sure if there is any way to change the way the microphone opens for input and closes after input.

Should I use the Dialogflow API or what should I look towards to solve my problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**No, changing the open mic period is not possible**

You cannot directly change the amount of time that the microphone stays open in a conversation with Google Assistant. Google automatically closes the conversation as soon as no input is heard from a person.

**Responding when the user is silent**

What you can do is create an event in Dialogflow that triggers on the actions on google `no_input` [event](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/reprompts#actions_sdk). With this event you can start a response once the assistant doesn't hear any input, some example responses could be:

- Hey, are you still there?
- Hmm, I didn't hear you, could you repeat that?
- etc.